# Do not search within bbCode tags

Tags: php, search, bbcode

I have a ordinary bbCode function that search for for example `[b]` and `[/b]` in my posts and replace these with for example bold text. When a visitor search some a post on my blog, it can happen that he or she search after something that is a filename for a image (`[img]path/to/image.jpg[/img]`). If this happens, the image will be gone from the post due to the highlighting.

How can I make the search engine (which is a regular `WHERE column LIKE '%string%'`) to **not** search within my bbCodes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want is essentially impossible (or at least so incredibly ugly that you do NOT want to go there) in standard "simple" sql.

Comment: Oh. Okey. That's just sad to know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another clause to exclude certain tags:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%string%'
AND column NOT LIKE '%[img]%[/img]%'
```

Note that doing so will exclude all results with an [img] tag inside, even if there are other tags you may want to consider. Since this is probably not what you really want, you should leave your query as it is and do the replacement with a regular expression in PHP.

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't think about it as you did now. But when I have done what you suggested it didn't showed all posts. It just didn't show the results. I have it like this: `WHERE data_message LIKE '%".SEARCH."%' AND data_message NOT LIKE '%[img]%[/img]%'`. `SEARCH` contains the search string.

Comment: Well that looks ok at first glance if `SEARCH` is a constant string. I'd play around with the SQL query and with the code to see if there are any other syntax errors. Otherwise, there may just be no matches to the query.

Comment: `SEARCH` can contain any character so I think it's because of that?

Comment: Maybe. The query only returns results that fulfil both conditions: `SEARCH` must be there and `[img]` must be missing. By the way, since `SEARCH` is not constant you should escape it with `mysql_escape_real_string` or similar to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks. Yea. I have tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string` but my webhost doesn't allow that function or something like that.

Comment: Aargh, ok, then google for a manual replacement to `mysql_real_escape_string`, I'm not a PHP expert but I'm sure it has to be there.